# Are there benefits to using DDP with pandarallel?

Tags: pandas, pytorch, distributed-computing, slurm, pandarallel

I have a ML task, and as a preprocessing step, there is a lot of work on CPU to be done which can take >1 hour. Before, I was using the [pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel) library to parallelize this work, the documentation says that it will use all CPUs.
But when using pytorch DDP on slurm, now there are multiple (4) processes running. I can have just one process run as before, or I can split the csv into 4 partitions and then run each of those in parallel.

Is this second approach faster, or am I just redundantly parallelizing?

I know that DDP is multiprocess but I'm not sure about the pandarallel library. I do notice that I need to specify less workers per DDP process for pandarallel when running with DDP, else I will get an OOM error.

Comment: I'm confused, why would you be using both at the same time? It sounds like the `pandaparallel` step is a multi-CPU process used for preprocessing data, while torch `DDP` is for parallelizing a model over multiple GPUs.

Comment: I want to use DDP so my code runs faster but I also have a cpu-heavy preprocessing step before the gpu heavy step. I don't think you can really opt-out of DDP once you start it though since your code will run 1 time per process. I could run it on one processs only but I'm not sure if it's inefficient